# Spark: extract value from map based on another column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|user_id             |map_data                                                                                             |key_field.       |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|VG1uTie2pzg5E89148k9|[2.0 -> [11.0, another_val_for_key_2], 1.0 -> [22.0, another_val_for_key_1]]                         |1                |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

and the following case class

```
case class A(d:Double, str: String)
```

map_data is a column of type Map[Double, A]

I am trying to create a new column that is based on the map_data column and the key_field column.

Something in the form of

```
df
.withColumn("value_from_map",
 col("map_data").getItem(col("key_field").cast(DoubleType)).getItem("str"))
```

When I'm using hardcoded key it works, for example:

```
df
.withColumn("value_from_map",
 col("map_data").getItem(2).getItem("str"))
```

so I'm not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solved it with a UDF function

```
val extract = udf( (key: Int, map: Map[Double, GenericRowWithSchema]) =>
        map(key).getAs[String]("str")
      )

...

.withColumn("value_from_map", extract(col("key_field"), col("map_data")))
```